# Cannot resolve symbol 'activityInfo'

Tags: java, android, android-intent

The line with "r.activityInfo" returns "error: cannot find symbol variable activityInfo" on compiling

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("LP1", "Created");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, android.net.Uri.parse("http://abc"));
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    final List<ResolveInfo> browsList = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( mainIntent, 0);
    Iterator itr = browsList.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        Object r = itr.next();
        ActivityInfo s = r.activityInfo;
    }
```

...
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `Object r`, but the `Object` class has not member named `activityInfo`.

To fix this, use an enhanced for loop:

```
for (ResolveInfo r : browsList) {
    ActivityInfo s = r.activityInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a cast or use for each cycle.

```
while(itr.hasNext()) {
        ResolveInfo r = (ResolveInfo)itr.next();
        ActivityInfo s = r.activityInfo;
    }
```

Comment: Better would be to use generics and make the cast irrelevant.